# When can a Color Ramp be used to create a gradiant in a Cycles shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders

When can you use a ColorRamp node or better to say where can you use a color ramp to manipulate the color of the mesh to be a gradient and not solid?

I tried to plug the ColorRamp in to the Color input of the Diffuse shader, but I didn't get a gradient, instead I always got one color.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *ColorRamp* node only remaps existing information. So without an input, you will only get a solid color as output (the solid color in the middle of the ramp, to be exact).

This is easily fixed by providing an input, such as a procedural *gradient texture* node:

[image]

Comment: itsh ard for me not to say thnaks to you lol. Yeah i know me and my usefull comments.The funny thing is i wondered how do i give this Gradient texture Color :D

Comment: by the way is it possible to import gradients ?