# How would I get brighter color with the voronoi node?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I haven't used the texture nodes much but was experimenting with them today. From everything I have tried, the voronoi node always ends up kind of dark. I like the look of it, but the only thing that comes close in shapes while giving me the brightness I want is the Musgrave node. And it's still not really there. Can anyone help point me in the right direction? My node setups are below for each as well as a low sample Suzanne to help show what I'm talking about. The Musgrave gives much brighter color in comparison. Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Be warned, the reason it appears brighter is the musgrave texture can return values > 1. In your setup this sort of turns the diffuse node into an emission node, as it will then reflect more light than it receives (which is not very physically accurate).

Comment: Have you tried a *Color* > *Brightness/Contrast*, *Hue/Saturation*, or *RGB Curves* node?  I'd also suggest just making your light brighter.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use the ColorRamp node. It permits not only to color but also to adjust the brightness of the result. This can help you: [When can a Color Ramp be used to create a gradiant in a Cycles shader?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19075/when-can-a-color-ramp-be-used-to-create-a-gradiant-in-a-cycles-shader)